# How to write a mysql with respect to the following conditions

Tags: mysql

I have 3 table

tmp (pid,title,price)

tmp_studyarea(areaid, tittle, tm_pid)

tmp_module(mid,title, duration, areaid)

I am trying to write a query where I can obtain (tmp.pid, tmp.title, tmp.price, SUM(tmp_module.duration Where tmp_module.areaid = tmpstudyarea.areaid and tmp_studyarea.tmp_pid = tmp.pid) Group by tmp.pid

Here is a query I wrote and i'm unable to get expected results. Help please

```
SELECT s.title, s.pid, SUM(duration) IN (SELECT a.tmpid, a.areaid, a.title, SUM(m.duration) as duration FROM tmp_studyarea AS a, tmp, tmp_module as m WHERE m.areaid = a.areaid AND a.tmpid = s.pid GROUP BY a.areaid) FROM tmp as s;
```

Here is my expected resultst

| title | pid | duration |
| --- | --- | --- |
| tmp Title 1 | 1 | 3000 |
| tmp Title 3 | 4 | 1000 |

**EDIT**

Found a solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT s.title,s.pid, (SELECT SUM(m.duration) as duration FROM tmp_studyarea AS a, tmp_module as m WHERE m.areaid = a.areaid AND a.tmpid = s.pid GROUP BY a.tmpid) as duration FROM tmp as s, tmp_studyarea, tmp_module GROUP by pid
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must join the 3 tables properly and aggregate:

```
SELECT t.pid, t.title, t.price,
       SUM(m.duration) total_duration
FROM tmp t
INNER JOIN tmp_studyarea s ON s.tmp_pid = t.pid
INNER JOIN tmp_module m ON m.areaid = s.areaid
GROUP BY t.pid, t.title, t.price
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion works like charm!!!. Please what are the possible problems I can face if the tables aren't properly aggregated?. Just curious

Comment: @Anseloh this is a very broad subject. If you search SO you will find many questions/answers dealing with aggregation.